# Boost Jam Not Producing Thread Library on Windows

Tags: boost, build-process, multithreading, bjam

I downloaded the latest Boost Jam binary from SourceForge and I'm using the command:

```
bjam toolset=gcc --build-type=complete stage
```

I've installed Cygwin along with the GCC compiler.  While the command produces a *stage/lib* directory, I cannot find the thread library that I'm using in Linux.  Boost Jam takes a while to run, so there could have been errors along the way.  Can anyone guess as to why I don't have the thread library?  Is there a specific command I can run in an attempt to only build the thread library?  Thanks!

Comment: You can certainly build just the threading library - I can't remember how, but we restrict our boost build to just a couple of modules.

Answer (score 0):

You most definitely need to check for, and provide the error messages. You can also try passing either `threadapi=pthread` or `threadapi=win32` to Boost.Build invocation.

In general, using the GNU/Kernel32.dll operating system, sometimes referred to as Cygwin, is risky business. Will using the native port of gcc, from mingw, be sufficient for you?